# APScheduler not executing the python

Tags: python, cron, apscheduler

I am learning Python and was tinkering with Advanced scheduler. I am not able to gt it working though.

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler

sched = Scheduler(standalone=True)
sched.start()

#@sched.cron_schedule(second=5)
def s():
    print "hi"
sched.add_interval_job(s, seconds=10)
i=0
while True:
  print i
  i=i+1
  time.sleep(3)
sched.shutdown()
```

I am sure I am missing something basic. Could someone please point it out?

Also would you recommend a crontab to the advanced scheduler? I want my script to run every 24 hours.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Standalone mode means that sched.start() will block, so the code below it will NOT be executed. So first create the scheduler, then add the interval job and finally start the scheduler.

As for the crontab, how about just sched.add_cron_job(s, hour=0)? That will execute it at midnight every day.